# How to fetch Plugin version number in Twilio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I am trying to get the latest version number of flex plugin in JavaScript. I could not find any documentation online and I was wondering if it's possible to fetch plugin version number in react app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making a GET Request. Follow an example of a request:

Request method: **GET**

Request URL: **https://flex-api.twilio.com/v1/PluginService/Plugins**

Authentication Type: **Basic**

Authentication **credentials: accountSid:authToken** (accountSid is the username and authToken is the password)

After the run, you will receive a list with 50 plugins :D.

I hope that it can help you!